# How to efficiently paginate a PHP array?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, arrays, pagination

I have an array currently paginated by using URL parameters (eg. ....php?page=2&blah=blop&glob=gloo).

At the moment, every single time the page loads, an XML file is being downloaded from a query engine, parsed and then im pulling an array of objects out I want to use.

How do I set this up so that I don't have to reload the page and only have to read from the XML file once?

I am fairly new to PHP so please bear with me. After a bit of researching I did I think Ajax is appropriate for this? Please correct me if I am wrong. I tried to find out some stuff on paginating with Ajax but the most useful things I found were for paginating data from a mysql database, not for an array of objects.

Can anyone provide any pointers? I'm eager to learn.

Comment: Unless you use some sort of in-memory cache (memcached) you will have to read the xml file (or some locally stored version of it) every time you need more data from it.  Is your real concern the server<->xml communication time or browser<->server communication time?

Comment: My biggest concern here is having the pagination on one page without having a page-load. This is a mobile app so I want the interface as streamlined as possible!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When I need this, I create a caching function that either A) Loads the XML from the original source and then saves it to a cache folder, or B) Loads it from the cache folder if it exists, and other criteria (like freshness) is met.

On one site that had to retrieve data from a fairly slow server, I put A) into a cron job and always read from the cache for the website.

If you need large data pagination, here's a good example: http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/php/how-to-paginate-data-with-php/

Comment: Thanks for the tips regarding the caching Matt. The XML source is going to rarely change so that's a good idea.

About the pagination, I already coded my own PHP Pagination, but I want to get rid of page loads, how would I do that?

Comment: Matt H is describing a File Cache.  Basically do a `file_get_contents('url to XML')` only if a `file_exists('path to cache file')` fails.  Otherwise you `file_get_contents('path to cache file')`.

Comment: If you want to entirely get rid of page loads, then use the answer below (AJAX) from @imkingdavid. You could load each page via an AJAX query, or load all the data at once into, say, a JSON array, and construct the page view when requested. JSON is okay if you have a finite amount of data, otherwise use a combination of AJAX loads for several pages at once, held in a JSON object.

Answer (score 1):

You could adapt the AJAX that you found for working with the database to work with your data object instead, so that the page is only loaded once.

Comment: Most the sources I found refer to a pagination class which is specifically for use with MySQL :-/

Comment: It may be made specifically for MySQL, but it should be adaptable for use with other types of data storage (i.e. XML). Can you link to the class?

Answer (score 0):

You can cache the XML either in memory using `memcached` or by saving it to a local file and read from there.

Additionally you can save it to a different, faster format(maybe `json`?) and split it into files - one file for each page - and only read the file for the page you need.

If the file is user-specific then other option would be to save it in the session(if it's not too big in array form), or if you want to save it in a file then prepend the session-id to the file name.

It is all very depending on what you want to do with the file and it's contents.

Answer (score 0):

You may be interested on this class for [php paginations](http://www.aprender-a-programar.com/paginacion-php).